# How to set the partition key in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am a little confused about cassandra's key defintion concept.

For example, I have a table `students`, it has following columns:

`student_id`: (text) and it is unique
`name`: (text)
`comments`: (text) also unique

Question: which column should I take as partition key? What is multiple partition key?

If I take only student_id as partition key, then, each partition will only contain one record, since student_id is unique.

```
CREATE TABLE students ( student_id text PRIMARY KEY, 
                        name text, 
                        comment text);
```

What about if I take two partition keys, like the following? The `name` column is not unique, will it make more sense when I put it into partition key with student_id?

```
CREATE TABLE students (student_id text, 
                       name text, 
                       comment text, 
                       PRIMARY KEY ((student_id, name), comment))
```

Comment: how are you going to query it? model cassandra schema around queries not the data

Comment: I want to query with student_id. But since student_id is unqiue, I worried about that too many partitions will be created... and each partition contains only one record...

Comment: things work pretty well up to about 1-4 billion partitions per node, then if doing full repairs with LeveledCompactionStrategy theres some perf issues. But tens of billions can still work. For tens or hundreds of millions per node theres no worries. What kind of volume of data do you expect? how big will your cluster be? That said smaller partitions does have a performance impact to compactions so if this table is super high throughput (tens of mb/s to disk) it might have issues.

Comment: I am still in learning, have no idea about how large the dataset will be... Thanks very much for the answer! :D